# Desktop vs mobile formating

Tags: discussion, tags, questions

I recently asked a question:
[Ruin, has come to our family](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/63467/ruin-has-come-to-our-family)

In this the answer depended on seeing the words formated in a certain way so they looked like steps and occurred n number of words into the line. I didn't think whilst creating this about how mobiles would format the text differently. Is there a tag for this, or a way of letting people know without giving too much away about the puzzle?

Answer (score 1):

The first thing I'd like to note is that when Stack Exchange changes the design, especially the width of the main bar (now set to a fixed value of 728 pixels wide), your puzzle may break (even on desktop). Therefore, it might be better to include an *image* of the letter (which you can use to add more 'feeling'/'texture' to your puzzle as well).

If you choose a font which is legible but not 'optimized' for reading text, you might include a transcript of the letter into your puzzle as well. That transcript doesn't need to be formatted as the text in your puzzle. An example of this can be found [here](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/30532/11110), though I haven't checked if the formatting is vital to solving that puzzle as it is in yours.

Answer (score 1):

If all you need is to have line breaks in certain places, you can accomplish that in several ways:

1. End a line with 2 spaces, then a carriage return
2. Include a `<BR>` tag at the end of the line (HTML for line break)
3. Use fixed width text (indent everything with 4 spaces)

The last option might be particularly relevant, because it will prevent "soft" line breaks (breaks that happen just because the screen isn't wide enough).

```
So you can
arbitrarily decide how long each line is
And if a line is too long to fit in the available space, you will get a scroll bar instead of having it wrap to the next line
```